# Will a Strong Motivation Make Me Stand Out in the phd application?

Tags: phd, motivation

My background is close to optimisation, but the position I like is closer to computer vision.

Comment: What do you mean by "strong motivation"? Strong compared to what/who? What will you use to demonstrate motivation in your application besides saying "I'm very motivated"?

Comment: this is a good question. for example, I was actively connecting potential teachers for similar project? is there any other suggestions on how to show my strong motivation? I already did mention my child dream and child experience, but I remember some people mentioned no body cares about my child dream

Comment: "Strong motivation" can only make you stand out if the rest of the candidates do not have "strong motivation". Do you imagine that most of the other applicants do not have "strong motivation"?

Comment: To possibly paraphrase, as someone who is trained in optimization you want apply your training to optimize your motivation letter for a non-optimizing field?

Answer (score 1):

Strong motivation is necessary but not sufficient. There are a lot of factors in a doctoral application and others are probably more important. In the US, letters of support that predict a successful outcome weigh strongly.

The competition can be very intense, and many (most?) of the other applicants will also be highly motivated.

If you have lacks/deficits in some areas, look to shoring up those primarily.

Comment: now there are 6 applicants in the Linkedin. I have emailed the professor for updating my documents and motivation letter. I might update my motivation letter again in the uni system. I like that project very much.

Answer (score 0):

Motivation by itself does not help. You need to show that it translates to positive action. Don't try to convince someone you are motivated about a topic. This will typically not help and at the worst annoy people.

Use that motivation to read up about the topic and include details and background knowledge in your application letter. Make sure that if you get to the interview stage you truly know as much as you can about the topic and still be aware that you probably only scratched the surface.